# why react tooltip test case fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-tooltip

Checkout the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-chatterjee-42p2iw?file=%2Fsrc%2F__tests__%2Ftooltip.js%3A22%2C47-22%2C56)

Hover on the icon and inspect element, you'll see a `div` with an id of `doc_entry`, but this fails when I write test for it.

```
it('render tooltip content', async () => {
  const {container} = render(<ToolTip />)

  const labelElement = container.querySelector(
    `span[data-tooltip-id="doc_entry"]`,
  )
  expect(labelElement).toBeInTheDocument()

  fireEvent.mouseOver(labelElement)

  await waitFor(() => {
    const tooltip = container.querySelector('#doc_entry')
    expect(tooltip).toBeInTheDocument() // Fails here
    expect(tooltip).toHaveTextContent(/doc_entry/i)
  })
})
```

ToolTip component

```
import {Tooltip as ReactTooltip} from 'react-tooltip'

const ToolTip = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Hover =>
        <span data-tooltip-id="doc_entry" role="img" aria-label="goat">
          
        </span>
      </h1>
      <ReactTooltip tabIndex="-1" id={'doc_entry'} place="bottom">
        doc_entry
      </ReactTooltip>
    </>
  )
}

export default ToolTip
```

What changes are requried to pass this test and check the content inside of the tooltip?

Comment: You can try with `fireEvent.mouseEnter(labelElement)` instead of `mouseOver`

Comment: @Teneff I tried that but didnt work. I found a fix checkout this issue on github: https://github.com/ReactTooltip/react-tooltip/issues/716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed here at `react-tooltip` issues: https://github.com/ReactTooltip/react-tooltip/issues/716#issuecomment-907109769